# Removing a ContentView from List Activity

Tags: java, android, view

I have a simple list activity that shows all the file sin a certain directory. When I have at least one checked, I want a button to show up OVER the list at the bottom, I don't want it to be part of the list, because then you have to scroll all the way to the bottom to see the button. I have the button showing up, which is great, but I have a problem. After I add the button, I can't remove it. I want it removed when no files are checked. Here's my code

```
    if(size == 1) {
                Log.d("LIST", "Showing button!");

                Button button = new Button(selectFile.getApplicationContext());
                button.setId(556);
                button.setText("Click me to " + (SHRED_MODE ? "Shred!" : "Encrypt/Delete!"));
                   LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                 selectFile.addContentView(button, params);
            } else if (size == 0) {
                Log.d("LIST", "Removing Button!");
                View view = selectFile.findViewById(556);
                if(view == null) {
                    Log.d("List", "VIEW IS NULL");
                    return;
                }
                selectFile.getListView().removeView(view);
            }
```

I don't see anything like a removeContentView, and when I use removeView, I get this exception

```
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.widget.AdapterView.removeView(AdapterView.java:489)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at austin.paid.productions.SelectFile$EfficientAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(SelectFile.java:134)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-12 13:38:33.371: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: @Austin: Wouldn't it be simpler to just create an AlertDialog? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: @MisterSquonk I never noticed that, I'll try that and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @MisterSquonk AlertDialogue would have something pop up in front of them, I don't really want that. I want them to be able to still utilize the List.

Comment: @Austin: OK, what about having a Button permanently below the ListView and simply enable/disable it as necessary?

Comment: What is selectFile? The instance of your ListActivity?

Comment: @Noel Yep. @MisterQuonk Alright I'm doing that, but when the button is disabled, it's placed right over an item on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not only attempting to remove something from an `AdapterView` via `removeView()` -- which, as the stack trace indicates, is not allowed -- but that's not where the `View` is that you are trying to remove.

You added the `View` via:

```
selectFile.addContentView(button, params);
```

I presume that `selectFile` is an `Activity` instance, since that's the most likely candidate for what would respond to `addContentView()`.

An `Activity` is not a `ListView`. `selectFile` is not `selectFile.getListView()`. You cannot remove a child you added to `selectFile` by trying to remove it from something that is not `selectFile`.

And, AFAICT, you cannot remove something you added via `addContentView()`, anyway.

So, please, follow @MisterSquonk's recommendation, and just have a fixed button at the bottom of the layout.

Also, do not call `getApplicationContext()` unless you *specifically need the `Application` object*. You do not need the `Application` object here. In fact, for GUI work, you almost never need the `Application` object. Please just pass the `Activity` to the `Button` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, there are better ways to accomplish your particular needs. However, for completeness, there is a way to do what you want.

If you added a View (button) to an Activity (selectFile) using this:

`selectFile.addContentView(button, params);`

...you would remove it like this:

`ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) button.getParent();
parent.removeView(button);`